# JOIN between tables

Tags: php

I have a little trouble with a query.

I have this DB structure

PROCESSES
process_id
process_name

ITENS
item_id
item_process_id
item_name

FILES
file_id
file_item_id
file_name

I run this query to obtain Process ID:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM processes WHERE process_id='$process_id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
$process_id = $row['process_id'];
```

Put this ID in a LOOP to obtain all Itens from table:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM itens WHERE item_process_id='$process_id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
```

And call Item name into a LOOP

Problem is when i try to call "file_name" from FILES table.
I have tried with a LEFT JOIN to table but with no success.
"file_name" variable is blank

Can anyone help me to understand how solve this?

TKS

Comment: what does your query to `files` look like? Are you sure there is data?

Comment: yes, i have data on FILES table

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM itens LEFT JOIN FILES ON FILES.item_id = itens.item_id WHERE itens.item_process_id='$process_id'"`. Remember that LEFT JOIN retrieve ALL result of the first table (itens) and join it to the table FILES and fill with NULL value on the FILES side if there is NO coressponding entry. That's may be why you could have empty value (if you don't have file for some iten)

Comment: @user2112020 post your files query, you probably have a join wrong

Comment: Oh My, Worked Now... I Dont't Understand, maybe I have worked a Lot for today...

I have added a simply JOIN.

TKS for ALL

Comment: Take care of INNER JOIN that could hide you some result from itens if there is no corresponding file. good luck

Comment: Here Working Query:
$query="SELECT * FROM itens
LEFT JOIN files ON file_id = file_item_id
WHERE process_id='$process_id'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try LEFT JOIN files ON file_id = file_item_id